# pm2 unexpectedly went down - " Error: ENOSPC, write "

Tags: linux, node.js, centos, pm2

I use pm2 for running a node.js app that provides restFul api for my front end app.
It was all good until this morning I started seeing errors and when I go to the terminal and start getting:

```
" Error: ENOSPC, write "
```

for anything that I did (including pm2 -v). Some quick research and try out - it started working when I run it with sudo. (sudo pm2 start ... ).
Obviously I don't like the solution :) and want to get to the bottom of it. Anyone had similar situations ? 
Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with space. Deleted unnecessary files to get the behaviour back